# Python button timeout

Tags: python, timeout, raspberry-pi3

There are two buttons on raspberry pi. I want the functionality in such way:

If button 1 is pressed - it will wait for 10 seconds to check if the button 2 is pressed. If in that 10 seconds button 2 is pressed then the code of button 2 should execute. And if button 2 is not pressed  in that 10 seconds then code of button 1 should execute.

Please tell me how i can achieve this functionality in python.

My button code is as below:

```
#Button One
button_state = GPIO.input(17)
    if button_state == False:
        GPIO.output(5,GPIO.HIGH)
        print('Button One Pressed')
        time.sleep(10)
    else:
        GPIO.output(5,GPIO.LOW)

#Button Two
    button_state = GPIO.input(24)
    if button_state == False:
        GPIO.output(26,GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(26,GPIO.LOW)
        print('exit')           
        break
    else:
        GPIO.output(26,GPIO.LOW)
```

Comment: Using `time.sleep()` and conditionals ?

Comment: I tried that but didn't work for me. @BcK